# Mg in bacteriochlorophyll

Tags: photosynthesis, chloroplasts

In the figure 1A of http://photobiology.info/Jones.html
the Mg is not belong to other structure.
Is that because something is omitted or is it indeed like a pearl in a mussel's mouth? In the later case could we replace the Mg by some other atoms (and the bacteriochlorophyll still live well)?

Comment: The Mg atom is not bound in the porphyrin ring, it is coordinated there.

Comment: http://photobiology.info/Jones.html
The author of the above page told me              The magnesium (purple sphere) is bonded to the four pyrrole nitrogens (the four blue atoms pointing towards it.

Comment: I checked chemistry books "coordinate" means the shared electron all came from one party ? So,what is the difference between bounded and coordinated?

Comment: When the atom is bound, chemical bounds are formed. If it is coordinated, it is kept in place by interaction between the atoms (for example by van der Waals force).

Comment: So, both Mg in chlorophyll and Fe in RC are coordinated? Will a coordinated atom have a fixed orientation with other atoms?